# EasyUI change option 'required' dynamically

Tags: combobox, required, jquery-easyui

in html:

```
 <input id="iCheck" 
    class="easyui-switchbutton"
    data-options="onChange:iCheckChange"
 >
 <input id="iCombo"
    class="easyui-combobox"
    data-options="mode:'remote'
                , disabled: true
                , required: false
                , loader: ...
                "
  >
```

in script

```
function iCheckChange(aChecked){
  $('#iCombo').combobox(aChecked?'enable':'disable').combobox('options').required = aChecked;
};
```

Code: https://jsfiddle.net/0dbog4of/4/

How repaint iCombo as iCombo2 ?
change 'required' option don`t redraw component :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script>  
  function iCheckChange(aChecked){
   $('#iCombo').combobox(aChecked?'enable':'disable');
   $('#iCombo').combobox('options').required = aChecked;
   $('#iCombo').combobox('textbox').validatebox('options').required = aChecked;
   $('#iCombo').combobox('validate');
};
</script>
```

http://www.jeasyui.com/forum/index.php?topic=6593.0